# Eclipse and Ant

Tags: java, eclipse

While creating project in eclipse, does Eclipse use Ant as build tool to build the project. I cannot see build.xml in eclipse. Please can anyone explain the connection between eclipse and Ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Eclipse, by default, uses its own build settings which have no connection to Ant. You can configure them by right-clicking on the project and choosing Properties. Ant and Eclipse were developed separately.

By the way, I should point out that I think Maven is now the most popular build system in the Java community, and for that you can use the m2e Eclipse plugin to make Eclipse use the Maven `pom.xml` file (which is kind of like Ant's `build.xml`, but for Maven) for builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly connect Eclipse to your pre-existing ant build, you need to use http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/ant/ -- the Eclipse Platform Ant Project.

Otherwise, while Eclipse will cheerfully look at your build.xml as part of building an Eclipse project from your sources, it will do all of its building with its own internal tools.

Comment: The ant project is included in most Eclipse downloads, but you still have to run ant builds manually.